# Duplicate identifier '"moment"' in my project

Tags: angular, npm

I am new to Angular and front-end development. When I executed the build procedure, it throw an error saying below context.

```
../../../../../../../node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment.d.ts(2,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '"moment"'.
../../../../../../../node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment.d.ts(4,19): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '"moment"'.
../../../../../../../node_modules/moment-timezone/index.d.ts(3,16): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '"moment"'.
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I think that it should be some mismatched version issue on `moment` modules but I am hard to figure it out why this error happens.

Below is my `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --live-reload false",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:stats": "ng build --stats-json",
    "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer -p 9999 target/classes/resource/stats.json",
    "prod": "node --max_old_space_size=10240 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --deploy-url /resource/ --output-hashing all --base-href /app/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/nx lint && ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "affected:apps": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:build",
    "affected:e2e": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:test": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:test",
    "affected:lint": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:lint",
    "affected:dep-graph": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "./node_modules/.bin/nx affected",
    "format": "./node_modules/.bin/nx format:write",
    "format:write": "./node_modules/.bin/nx format:write",
    "format:check": "./node_modules/.bin/nx format:check",
    "update": "ng update @nrwl/schematics",
    "update:check": "ng update",
    "workspace-schematic": "./node_modules/.bin/nx workspace-schematic",
    "dep-graph": "./node_modules/.bin/nx dep-graph",
    "help": "./node_modules/.bin/nx help",
    "build:lib:page-grid": "ng-packagr -p libs/page/grid/ng-package.json",
    "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p ./apps/metatron-apm/tsconfig.app.json -s"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.20.5",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nrwl/nx": "7.5.2",
    "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "7.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.9.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "daterangepicker": "^3.0.5",
    "echarts": "^4.2.0-rc.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "jquery": "1.12.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.2.2",
    "ngx-quill": "^6.3.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.2",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^3.0.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-mention": "^2.2.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "sockjs-client": "1.3.0",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^3.3.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.4.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.0",
    "@nrwl/builders": "7.5.2",
    "@nrwl/schematics": "7.5.2",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/echarts": "^4.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^23.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.120",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cypress": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jest": "^23.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "6.0.1",
    "ng-packagr": "^4.6.0",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
    "prettier": "1.15.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": ">=0.29.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "validator": "^10.11.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

and my node version is `v10.12.0`.

Comment: Add "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json and check.

Comment: Try  'npm dedupe' if it doesn't work then 'npm uninstall moment' followed by a install of a different version.  'npm install moment@version

Comment: @VaritJPatel When I set the true in skipLibcheck, then `tz properties does not exist` error is shown..

Comment: Probably this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970643/angular-6-failed-compile-property-tz-does-not-exist-on-type-moment